# Magento import custom linked products in csv

Tags: csv, magento, magmi

We have developed a Megento website and filled it with products. In this website we have the standard Magento related products which we can import with a CSV file.

However, we have installed Inchoo's Custom Linked Products as well. Is there a way in which we can import this in a CSV as well? How should the column be named?

We use Magmi for the import.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'll post the question at Magento Stack Exchange. Regards, Erik